# Laravel - How to access related object other relashionship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 Models "Category", "Post", and "User".
A Category has a hasMany relationship with Post. And a Post has a belongsTo relationship with User.

I have a Category object `$cat1` and i can access its posts (and the user_id) in my view, but i can't access more user data (line name)

```
@foreach ($cat1->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    {{ $post->user()->name }}
@endforeach
```

This throws an error

> Undefined property: 
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
{{ $post->user->name }}
```

When you call the function, it's to query the relationship.

Comment: It doesn't work. Throws an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Badr Can you show your user method from your Post model?

Comment: `public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }` here it is.

Comment: I have other models with the same kind of relationship and it's working using your syntax, so i must have missed something else, checking..

Comment: @Badr And the property is `user_id` in your Post model?

Comment: i didn't define it in the Model but i did in the database migration, i can even access it using `{{ $post->user_id }}`

Comment: No problem @Badr!